# Call one stored procedure to another stored procedure in DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

Problem that I was facing is that I have to call one stored procedure from another stored procedure in DB2 database. Kind example that I am giving right below.

I have one stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc1()
 IS    
  Declare myName in varchar;
 BEGIN 
  Select fname into myName from student where fname='x'; // is returning unique value
  -- here call anoher proc2
 END;
```

Now so this proc1 procedure is going to call this proc2 procedure.

Now I have second stored procedure:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc2(Name in varchar)
 IS
 BEGIN
  -- do anything
 END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem,
So solution is like If we want to execute proc using sql command then syntex is like below,

```
call Proc2('My Name');
```

We can use this same approach inside our proc also. 
For that we have to follow some steps. Lets say that our above sql call is statement that we want to execute. we are going to convert that statement into String and pass necessary parameter by concating variable values. Then execute statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc1()
 IS
  Declare myName in varchar;
  -- stmt variable is to execute our proc
  STMT VARCHAR(4000);
 BEGIN 
  Select fname into myName from student where fname='x'; // is returning unique value
  -- this is our logic
  STMT :='call Proc2('||myName||')';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT;
 END;
```

Comment: You should be able to use `call Proc2(myName)` without having to resort to dynamic SQL as described in your own answer.  Are you unable to do this?  What error do you get?

Comment: when i do this, call `Proc2(myName)` it gives no proc found with such arguments. I nearly tried every options that I can think but failed for all.

Comment: You should definitely check what schema your procedures were created in, and what the `CURRENT PATH` for each procedure is (i.e. when you create `PROC2`, make sure that `CURRENT PATH` includes the schema that the procedure exists in.  Alternatively, fully qualify the procedure, i.e. `call schema.proc2(myName)`

Comment: @IanBjorhovde But when our app goes to production server schema name can change so i do not want to include my schema name in proc. It's going to be hard code. I use this approach that you suggest it works but i want to do without that.

Comment: If you don't want to hard code schema names in the text of the procedure, then you have to ensure that you set the value of `CURRENT PATH` appropriately for each environment when you're creating your stored procedures.